# How to tune the radial mode vibration of a PZT disc transducer?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, sensors

I am trying to create a set-up where I can radially vibrate a 1x1 cm sample using a piezoelectric disc transducer. I know that at the $f_{min}$ of a PZT transducer, for the disc geometry, there is a radial vibration. How can I tune this vibration if I want to vibrate my sample radially at different frequencies?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this post. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1883/what-is-radial-and-thickness-mode-vibration-in-a-piezo-electric-ceramic-disc-tra

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance on this topic,but what is the sample made out of. It is metal. Also you might want to look at this link too. http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2695/can-i-use-a-ultrasound-sensor-to-measure-water-level/2697#2697